# How can I find the distinct msg and its item's all attribute,by Mongoose?And also the count of msg occurs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose /Node.js
How can I find the distinct msg and its item's all attribute?
And also the count of msg occurs?

example:

```
var LogSchema = new Schema({
msg: {
    type: String
},
status: {
    type: String,
    default: '200'
}});
```

there are items in db:

```
{_id:'1',msg:'1',status:1},
{_id:'2',msg:'1',status:2},
{_id:'3',msg:'1',status:1},
{_id:'4',msg:'1',status:2},
{_id:'5',msg:'2',status:2},
{_id:'6',msg:'2',status:2},
{_id:'7',msg:'2',status:2},
```

The result I need is:

```
{_id:'1',msg:'1',status:1,count:4},
{_id:'5',msg:'2',status:1,count:3}
```

Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly.I displayed the result because `{_id:'1',msg:1,status:1}` occured first in the `msg:1` collections.Also `{_id:'5',msg:1,status:1}` occured first in the `msg:2` collections.All I need is to find out all the same 'msg' and the first one of them.

So,how should I write js code ?

Comment: To explain why you are getting downvoted, your data does not represent any logical reason "why" you should arrive at your expected results. I see `{ msg: 1, status: 1, count: 2}, { msg: 1, status: 2, count: 2 }` etc etc. So pretty much a poorly worded quesstion. What do you want to do?

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly.

Comment: That is basically the point. Edit your question, and then you might get a real answer that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation tools of MongoDB.

```
LogModel.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: '$msg',
           firstId: { $first: '$_id' },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Last,I find all of them and handle them with js code.
Like this:

```
Log.find({},needShow.join(' ')).exec(function(err, logs) {
if (!err) {
    //To find out the distinct one and the count of repeat
    var lastTime = new Date();
    logs.sort(function(pre,cur){
        return pre.time-cur.time;
    })
    var need = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < logs.length - 1; i++) {
        var item = logs[i].toObject();
            item.count = 1;
            item.ids = [item._id];

            var j = 0;
            for (; j < need.length; j++) {
                if (item.msg == need[j].msg) {
                    need[j].ids.push(logs[j]._id);
                    need[j].count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == need.length) {
                need.push(item);
            }
    }
} else {
    console.log(err);
}
})
```